# Xslt datetime conversion

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am receving the date in xsd:dateTime format "2021-10-20T15:30:46Z"  and I want to convert the same to "2021-10-20T15:30:46.000+04:00" in xslt 2.0.

I am not able to get the right picture string.

```
format-dateTime($DateTime, "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001]Z")
```

but it is returning "2021-10-20T15:30:46Z"

Comment: Are you sure that is the result you want? There is a 4 hours difference between your input and your output. When the time in GMT is 15:30, the time in your target timezone is 19:30.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of formatting. In order to get the result you want, you need to (a) subtract 4 hours from the given dateTime and (2) adjust the result to a timezone with offset of 4 hours:

```
adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime($DateTime) - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT4H'), xs:dayTimeDuration('PT4H'))
```

Comment: will try this and let you know.is it not possible to provide like this format-dateTime($DateTime, "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].000+04.00") .

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is it also correct? I don't think so, because the dateTime value is being changed., not reformatted. If you want to ignore that, you could do a simple string manipulation: `replace($DateTime, 'Z', '.000+04.00')`.